# Convert List<Date> to Map<Month, List<Date>>

Tags: java

I want to convert a list of dates to a map where the month is the key and the values is a list of dates with the given month.

I have the following month object, which basically is holding a month and a year int, so each month is unique.

```
    public class Month implements Serializable, Comparable<Month> {
        protected int year;
        protected int month;

       public Month(Date dag) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dag);
            this.month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1; //zerobased to onebased
            this.year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        }

    }
```

And now given a list of dates i try do do something like this:

```
     public void addLedigeDage(List<Date> newLedigeDage) {
        List<Date> datesPerMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            for (Date date : newLedigeDage) {
                cal.setTime(date);
                Month month = new Month(date);
                datesPerMonth = findAllDatesForGivenMonth(newLedigeDage, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                ledigeDageMap.put(month, datesPerMonth);
            }
        }


    private List<Date> findAllDatesForGivenMonth(List<Date> newLedigeDage, int month) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        List<Date> datesForGivenMonth = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Date date : newLedigeDage) {
            if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month ) {
                datesForGivenMonth.add(date);
            }
        }
        return datesForGivenMonth;
    }
```

But the code is not clean and not optimal, since i iterate over same dates too many times.

I am using java 1.7 and have Guava available. I cannot use a Multimap in this case, because of some architecture issues in my application.

Any suggestions on how to optimize this and make it clean?

Comment: You want code review? >> http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No i dont want a code review. Im looking for the right clean way to do it, and i just posted what i have tried so far.

Comment: And you want that someone looks over it and suggests better solutions. This is one of the goals of "Code Review".

Comment: "Any suggestions on how to optimise this and make it clean?". So... a review... of your code.

Comment: AFAIK part of a good question on SO is "What have you tried" and "post your code". I'm sorry if i have formulated the question in a wrong way. Would it make a difference if i asked the question without submitting my code? But thanks for your time, i will post the same question on stack exchange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd do something like:

```
public void addLedigeDage(List<Date> newLedigeDage) {
  for (Date date : newLedigeDage) {
    Month month = new Month(date);
    if (!ledigeDageMap.containsKey(month)) {
      ledigeDageMap.put(month, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    ledigeDageMap.get(month).add(date);
  }
}
```

If you wanted, you could then extract:

```
if (!ledigeDageMap.containsKey(month)) {
  ledigeDageMap.put(month, new ArrayList<>());
}
ledigeDageMap.get(month).add(date);
```

as a separate method called something like `addDateToMap` to be a bit cleaner.

Comment: I don't know guava, but I suspect you might be able to approve on the above with some guava magic.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant Java-8 solution:

```
    List<Date> dates = Arrays.asList(new Date(10000), new Date(100000));
    Map<Month, List<Date>> byMonth = dates.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(d -> new Month(d)));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code:
1st: Don't Lie in your code (Month contains month and year). Should be some more specific name.

2nd: override equals and hashcode method other wise two month object with same month and year value will be treated different by Map.

Apart from this DaveyDaveDave answer is good to go.

Comment: Month already has an equals and hashcode methods, which i chose not to post in this question, since they dont give any value to this question(the same with getters and setters). Also i have not programmed the Month class myself, im just working with existing code which i can't refactor in this Iteration.

Comment: Also it is a good practice to make fields your hashCode based on final.